# How to send https request using Python and Locust

Tags: c#, python, locust

I am using `Locust framework` and `Python`. I am writing `HTTP request` using 
`self.client.get / self.client.post` and I am observing these requests and response in Fiddler.

But when I checked for some https site using the same syntax I can not see it's response in Fiddler. The response code is 0 and response are coming null.

So is there any other way to send https requests?

I have imported following in my python file code - `HttpLocust, TaskSet, task, events, web, datetime, time`

I want to make request for mostly for java sites

So how can I send any `https request` using `Locust` and `Python`?

Comment: I dont understand the question. Are you asking how to send https requests using locust? That is trivial: just do a request that starts with https:// If your problem is that you dont see the https responses in fiddler then that is normal, because the request is encrypted...

Comment: I think you have to point to the certificate somehow. I'm myself in the process of figuring this out